# reset par() in functions

Tags: r, plot

When writing a plotting function in R, I'd like to not modify the global environment, so I include something like

```
op <- par()
on.exit(par(op))
```

But this is less than satisfactory because it spits out warning messages (e.g., `"In par(op) : graphical parameter "cin" cannot be set"`), but more importantly, it is not compatible with multi-panel plots. For example, if I had a simple function like

```
pfun <- function(x) {
    op <- par()
    on.exit(par(op))

    par(bg = "gray21", col = "deeppink", col.axis = "deeppink")
    plot(x, 
        xaxt = "n",
        yaxt = "n",
        col = "deeppink", 
        cex = 2, 
        pch = 22, 
        bg = "deeppink",
        col.lab = "deeppink")
    axis(1, col = "deeppink")
    axis(2, col = "deeppink")
}
```

it would work great for a single plot (apart from the warnings), but is incompatible with multi-panel plots, e.g.

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
pfun(1:10)
pfun(10:1) # overwrites the first plot rather than plotting in the second panel
```

Is there a way to have the plot parameters reset on exit while also allowing for multi-panel plotting?

Comment: see the description of `no.readonly` in `?par` what about adding an argument `reset_par` to your function so you can control if the par settings are reset or not. you can also add `par(mfg = c(1,1))` after the first `pfun`

Comment: Ah... thank you. The `no.readonly` part solved the warnings. I suppose I could add an additional argument to the function. I was hoping there was an alternative solution that wouldn't require any input from the user, but that's a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, that works too, but the larger context for this is a function within a package that people at my work are using and I'd rather not have to teach them all to precede each call to the function with `par(mfg = c(1, 1))` when doing multi-panel plotting. I'm thinking the additional argument may be the best option.

Comment: Maybe I should edit the original post but @rawr fixed the warning issue. I just needed to add `no.readonly = TRUE` to the call to `par()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can avoid interfering with multi-panel plots, by only saving /restoring the elements of `par` that we change in the function. In this case that means only storing `bg`, `col`, and `axis.col`. The important thing is to avoid interfering with the graphical parameters (particularly `mfrow`, `mfcol` and `mfg`) that control multiplot positions.

```
pfun <- function(x) {
  op <- par('bg', 'col', 'col.axis')
  on.exit(par(op))

  par(bg = "gray21", col = "deeppink", col.axis = "deeppink")
  plot(x, 
    xaxt = "n",
    yaxt = "n",
    col = "deeppink", 
    cex = 2, 
    pch = 22, 
    bg = "deeppink",
    col.lab = "deeppink")
  axis(1, col = "deeppink")
  axis(2, col = "deeppink")
}
```

Or, even slightly neater is to make use of the fact that when we set parameters with `par` it invisibly returns a list of the *old* values of the parameters we changed.  So just the following will work nicely:

```
  op <- par(bg = "gray21", col = "deeppink", col.axis = "deeppink")
  on.exit(par(op))
```

Comment: Beautiful! Really nicely done, and makes total sense. Thank you!